# Alter columnt type from int to bigint with minimal downtime

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

I have several tables with `id` columns that are declared to be serial (i.e. `integer` type with default `nextval()`).

Converting them to bigint seem to be quite straightforward:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ALTER COLUMN id
TYPE bigint;
```

But that might take a lot of time and lock the whole table. It's okay-ish solution for cases when the whole site is already down due to integer overflow, but not so good for provisional changes.

How would one do that `concurrently`?

Comment: Use logical replicaiton perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to do this without substantial downtime.

You would need to add a new column, change the code to populate but not rely on this new column when rows are inserted/updated, then populate the new column by copying from the old column with conversion and in chunks (to avoid locking problems, and possibly to throttle resource usage), then change the code to rely on the new column, then drop the old column.  It is not fun.

The system could do this work for you if it knew how long the field was in storage.  Then it could just up-convert from int to bigint on the fly when encountering old data with the sorter length.  But I don't think PostgreSQL stores the field length (on a per-row basis) for fixed length fields like int and bigint, so there is no way for it to reliably detect this.